# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Apple Push Notification Service Exception

Tags: ios, networking, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

All,

I am trying to get Apple Push Notification working on Mac. But I am having below issue and need some help to figure out what is going on.

I have implemented the Push Notification sample from Worklight's Getting Started page. I am able to install the app on My iPhone 4S and able to subscribe to the Push notification. I can see one user and subscription in my Worklight Console. When I executed the adapter procedure to push the notification to my device, I see message saying message has been sent to user: XXX. However, I then see the following error message:

```
[WARNING ] Failed to send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@30f6ea2a... trying again
[WARNING ] Failed to retreive invalid devices
[WARNING ] Failed to retreive invalid devices
[WARNING ] Failed to retreive invalid devices
[ERROR   ] Couldn't get feedback connection
[ERROR   ] Unknown exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com
[WARNING ] Failed to retreive invalid devices
[WARNING ] Failed to retreive invalid devices
[WARNING ] Failed to retreive invalid devices
[ERROR   ] Couldn't get feedback connection
[ERROR   ] Unknown exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com
```

While googling to find out the solution for above issue, suggestions were that there could be some network issue. I turned off the firewall and was able to ping the APNS servers.

```
$ telnet 1-courier.push.apple.com 5223
Trying 17.149.32.15...
Connected to 1.courier-push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.

$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.34.65...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.

$ telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.233.147...
Connected to gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I also tried to allow the below ports for APNS but no luck.

```
$ sudo ipfw add 0 allow tcp from any to any 2195
00100 allow ip from any to any proto tcp dst-port 2195
$ sudo ipfw add 0 allow tcp from any to any 5223
00200 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 5223
$ sudo ipfw add 0 allow tcp from any to any 2196
00300 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 2196
$ sudo ipfw add 0 allow tcp from any to any 443
00400 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 443
```

Worklight Version(Studio): V6.0
MacPro Configuration: Firewall is turned off
Wi-fi Router: Firewall is turned off
iPhone 4S: Notification is enabled in Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a matter of disabling your firewall... You can have it turned on, but make sure that the specific ports and IP address that belongs to Apple is allowed, [as Apple suggests in this support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4264?viewlocale=en_us&locale=en_us).

Comment: Idan, Thanks for editing the questions for clarity and for your answer.

Comment: Could you guide me on how i can make sure that these TCP ports on open on Mac?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this DNS issue? And how to resolve that?

Comment: The DNS servers of your ISP is not in sync with Apple's servers. But I doubt it...

Comment: Try it at home rather than at work, see if the change of networks makes a difference.

Comment: I tried different network but the problem does persist. I think i am missing something. Could somebody help?

Comment: How did you create the push certificate? How did you configure the Worklight project?

Comment: We followed this URL on WL push set up - http://myworklight.blogspot.com/2013/03/understanding-and-setting-up-artifacts.html.

Comment: Can you tell us if we have to follow any step outside that process mentioned in the above URL?

Comment: There aren't addionnal steps

Comment: I am trying to figure out what could be the issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Try with a different device, check the certificate, app id, provisionnig profile, all match - maybe it has to do with the "invalid device" error. also try with a sandbox certificate instead of a production certificate; see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @PaulDeepakRaj, any luck?